# Convert string to date and compare in php

Tags: php

I have a string and want to convert it into a date and then perform some compare and do some action. This is my scenario:

```
$a="2015-02-17" //yyyy-mm-dd
$b="2015-01-17" //yyyy-mm-dd
if ($a>$b)
{
//action1
}
else
{
//action2
}
```

Comment: https://eval.in/520967

Comment: <?php
//echo "wow";
// your code goes here
$a="2015-02-17"; //yyyy-mm-dd
$b="2015-01-17"; //yyyy-mm-dd
$a_date= date_create($a);
//echo $a;
$b_date= date_create($b);

if ($a_date>$b_date)
{
//action1
echo "a is bigger";
}
else
{
//action2
echo "b is bigger";
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$today = '2015-02-17';
$expire = '2015-01-01';

$today_time = strtotime($today);
$expire_time = strtotime($expire);

if ($expire_time < $today_time) {
//do some thing
}
```

If you are using PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, you could use the DateTime class:

```
$date1 = new DateTime($today);
$date2 = new DateTime($expire);

if ($date1 < $date2) { /* Do something */ }
```

Comment: thanks works as expected!